# Can I force a folder to only allow externals?

Tags: svn

We follow the standard trunk structure of having a lib folder in which we put DLL references.  We have a repository for holding such assemblies and generally don't have a problem with people following the practice but we have one dev who likes to build things on his own PC and drop them into a /lib folder without having gone through code control, the CI build server, or the assembly repository.

I'm wondering, is it possible to eliminate this behavior by making a folder only be able to contain extern entries?

(I keep trying to get this guy fired, don't ask...)

Comment: Best option: create a pre-commit hook which prevents any add operation in that directory. You can still edit existing items and even edit `svn:externals` but you won't be able to commit any new files or directories to it. If I had the code for the hook, I'd post it as an answer.